# How to convert arrays from PHP/MySQL to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am having difficulty with getting the JavaScript portion of this code to work the way I would like.

I have managed to pull the array from a MySQL table and convert it using JSON.

However, when I try to get the data into a HTML table, I get individual characters in each cell.

For example, my database has a table with a keyword labels. Inside this are 4 colors Blue, Green, Brown, Hazel exactly as I have entered it here.

When I output via JavaScript, I get one character in each cell instead of 4 cells.

I am "almost" there on my own:

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM variables WHERE id= '1' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $labels = $row["labels"];
    }
    foreach (explode(',', $labels) as $newLabel) {
        echo "{$newLabel} ";
    }
} 
?>
<script>

<?php $newLabel = $labels ?>
var n = <?php print (json_encode($newLabel)); ?>;
var index;
var myTable= "<table class='hover'>";


myTable+= "<tr><td class='smalltd'style='width: 20px; font-weight:bold;'></td>";
for (index = 0; index < newLabel.length; index++) {
    myTable+= "<td class='no' style='width: 100px; font-weight:bold;'>" 
           + newLabel[index] + "</td>";
}

myTable+="</table>";

document.write(myTable);
</script>
```

I suspect the culprit lies in the `newLabel.length` but I am not certain

Comment: What are you trying to with javascript

Comment: You know you can write Javascript with php ? You can then write... with php your needed javascript this time o_o

Comment: Where do you define 'newLabel' in your javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to collect your labels into an array, not a string:

```
$labels[] = $row["labels"];
```

Second, you've never defined the `newLabel` javascript variable.
Change

```
for (index = 0; index < newLabel.length; index++) {
```

to

```
for (index = 0; index < n.length; index++) {
```

and use `n` or rename `n` to `newLabel`

Comment: But i really wonder why he should write the table through JS and not echo through php

Comment: @IndraKumarS You are right. I've just try to find the errors in his code. Who knows, maybe he has some reason for it.

Comment: Thank you for all of the comments. The reason behind my insanity is that I try to create tough questions for myself and then solve them using a variety of languages. I feel this not only helps me to learn, but also keeps me in practice. My ultimate goal here is to place a user generated table into <canvas> and store the variables in a database.

Comment: lolka_bolka, you code above did help, but it is only adding one column in the table. Each comma separated word is still acting like one string. Is there a way to get each word in this array into separate columns?